# Interesting Question here - Why Tomorrow Date PHP and +1 Days Gives Different Time

Tags: php, web-deployment, phpcodesniffer, phpdebugbar, cakephp-helper

Hello PHP DEV,
I Want to know why this strange thing is happening!
Example :
strtotime("+1 days") returns time as UTC TIME which is current Time
so why strtotime('tomorrow') returns time as 00:00:00.

I noticed this show wants to know the official reason behind this.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php - The notes explain a bit on it, as well as the table named `Day-based Notations`

Comment: Still, Documentation is not clear for this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strtotime("+1 days")** uses current time and adds a day

**strtotime('tomorrow')** returns tomorrow at midnight (this is stated in the docs)

[datetime formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

> 'yesterday'    Midnight of yesterday   "yesterday 14:00"
> 'midnight'  The time is set to 00:00:00
> 'today' The time is set to 00:00:00
> 'now'   Now - this is simply ignored
> 'noon'  The time is set to 12:00:00 "yesterday noon"
> 'tomorrow'  Midnight of tomorrow